# godaddy SSL certificate shows domain name instead of full company name

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, domain-name

We just took a deluxe wildcard (*.example.com) certificate from godaddy. The process also included company name verification and company phone verification.

After installing, the browser (firefox) address bar just shows domain name on green instead of full legal company name. How to get the company name on the address bar? Is it something to do with the CSR?

Comment: Can you find any site that uses a wildcard certificate that behaves any differently in Firefox? I don't think you can. This is a result of an interaction between decisions by CA/B and decisions by Firefox. There's no known way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of that green bar come from the certificate itself, which you will have to get reissued to change it.  The certificate's O attribute in the subject (organization), along with the C attribute (country) determine what is displayed.  If they are absent, it will simply display the primary subject domain name from the certificate.

Also, the name (and usually the green bar) is only displayed for EV (extended validation) certificates.  If you don't have one, you would normally have just the domain name, or no information bar at all.  How this is displayed is of course dependent on the browser; recent versions of firefox display your domain name on a teal background in the address bar for non-EV certificates, whereas chrome just displays a lock icon and formats "https://" in green type.

You can't get a wildcard EV certificate, so to get this functionality in most browsers you would have to see if they would issue you an EV certificate with each of your subdomains as alternate names (the one that signs verisign.com is like this).

Verifying your company name and number, and usually inspecting your personal ID, incorporation, and a document giving you authority to act on behalf of the corporation are all expected parts of getting an SSL certificate issued in your company name at all.

Comment: Actually, I believe Firefox will do this no matter what is in the certificate (unless it's an EV certificate). Even though your CA validated all this stuff, the only way for them to *say* that they validated it is to issue an EV certificate (in fact, that was largely the point of EV certificates -- to tell others that extended validation was done). So Firefox has no way to know the CA validated and refuses to trust them.

Comment: Firefox will show only the domain name on a teal background for non-EV certificates, but it reserves the green background for EV ones, so I assumed OP had an EV certificate.  Editing...

Comment: GoDaddy does not offer EV wildcard certificates. In fact, nobody does. [CA/Browser Forum rules prohibit it](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/why-can-t-i-get-a-wildcard-extended-validation-ev-ssl-certificate/). "[Wildcard certificates are not allowed for EV SSL Certificates](http://www.cabforum.org/contents.html)."

Comment: Right.  Oops.  How could I forget.